# Java Split Packages with Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to modularize a Java application that is split into two Eclipse projects. My first cut had a module-info.java file for each project, but I got the message about split packages:
The package com.mycom.mygroup.myapp is accessible from more than one module
With Java 8 we built two JARs.

The structure of the application is:

Project one defines the packages

```
com.mycom.mygroup.myapp
com.mycom.mygroup.myapp.pack1
com.mycom.mygroup.myapp.pack2
```

Project 2 depends on project 1 and defines the packages

```
   com.mycom.mygroup.myapp.pack3
   com.mycom.mygroup.myapp.pack4
```

We are using Ant for our production builds. I think I could get it to work there.
If I leave out the module-info.java file for project 1, making it an automatic module, and build a JAR from the project 1 classes, I could get Project 2 to use the JAR. The problem is that I can't get Eclipse to be happy and I get 1000s of error messages. So I have to solve the split package problem.

If I restructure project 1 so that the first package name is 
com.mycom.mygroup.myapp.pack0, would that still be a split package?
My alternative appears to be to completely restructure the workspace and have
only one project.
Or is there a way to configure the build path in Eclipse so that Project 2 will see the classes in project 1 without making it a module.

Comment: Does project one contain the file `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` with `Automatic-Module-Name` or do you create this in the Ant script?

Comment: The manifest is created in the Ant script. I haven't gotten to adding the Automatic-Module-Name to the script. That wouldn't help with the Eclipse problem, but thanks for pointing it out. I may need to do that eventually.